# Who is we ? The we that appears in "we do no not run the site"

Tags: discussion

Who is we ? In other words who wrote "we do no not run the site"?
Curious question ? 
Curious questioner for sure !
Names, the names of people are so important in general. 
It all started with Avram/Abraham. 
No?

Comment: Please [edit] you question with a link to exactly where you found this. I suspect it was a comment from a site user, but without the context you've lifted the quote from it's pretty hard to interpret and explain.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the "we" you mention refers to the [moderators](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), perhaps that link will shed some light on your question.

The impression I get is that the site exists for the benefit of the contributors –you and me– but someone has to take on the responsibility for making sure folks abide by the rules so the standard of questions and answers remains high.

Comment: Lesley, I was obliged to add a tag. Elders seemed the least inappropriate and a bit funny ;-). I just discovered this site -after years of searching...Yes meta seems a good idea.